# Solve the following equation for $-180^\circ\leq x\leq 180^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

I am required to solve the following equation for $-180^\circ\leq x\leq 180^\circ$:

$$\sin2x=\tan x.$$

I am aware that I can convert $\sin2x = 2\sin x\cos x$.  However, I am not sure where to go from here to find the values for $x$ that will make the equation hold. 
 Any help with solving this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct approach. 
$2\sin{x}\cos{x}=\dfrac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}\Rightarrow \sin{x}(2\cos^2{x}-1)=0\Rightarrow \sin{x}\cos{2x}=0$

Now either $\sin{x}=0$ or $\cos{2x}=0$, for the first search all the solutions in $[-\pi,\pi]$ and for second $-\pi\le x\le \pi \Rightarrow -2\pi\le 2x\le 2\pi$. Thus first gives $x=0,\pi,-\pi$ and second gives $2x=\pm\frac{\pi}{2},\pm\frac{3\pi}{2}$, thus $x=\pm\frac{\pi}{4},\pm\frac{3\pi}{4}$. Thus solution set is $\{0,\pm\pi,\pm\frac{\pi}{4},\pm\frac{3\pi}{4}\}$.

Comment: Please can you show me how you have derive $0,±π,±\frac{π}{4},±\frac{3π}{4}$ an a final answer? 

The answer I can deduce at this point is  $0°$ and  $(\frac{π}{2})^° $, however I am unsure about the rest.

Comment: You should search for all possible answers in domain of x.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\sin(2x)-\tan(x)=$$

$$\sin (x)(2\cos (x)-\frac{1}{\cos (x)})=$$

$$\tan (x)\cos (2x)=0$$

$$x\in\{-180,-135,-45,0,45,135,180\}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: your equation can be written as
$$2\sin(x)\cos(x)-\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=0$$
and this is
$$\sin(x)\left(2\cos^2(x)-1\right)=0$$ if $$\cos(x)\ne 0$$
can you finish?

Comment: $\cos x$ multiply by itself is $\cos^2 x$. Not $\cos x^2$

Comment: i meant that, it is right now

Comment: Yes it is right now

Comment: it is not $\cos(2x)$ but $\cos^2(x)$

Comment: From this I can derive that $$sin(x)(2cos^2(x)−1)=0
$$
 $$=$$
$$sin(x)cos(2x)=0$$

For $sin =0$, I can use $0°$. for $cos2x=0$,  I can use $(\frac{π}{2})^° $

The two answers I can deduce are therefore $0°$ and  $(\frac{π}{2})^° $

I am still unsure how to derive $0,±π,±\frac{π}{4},±\frac{3π}{4}$ an a final answer

Answer (score 1):

Cancel out  $\sin x$.. that means $x= 2 p \pi$

Left out part is just $ \cos^2 x= \frac12$ that means $ x= q \pi/4$ all inclusive  so that $x= 2 p \pi$ can be ignored as repetition.